# If an astronaut needs to go to the toilet during launch, what can they do and what do they need to do?

Tags: astronauts, waste

It is clear everyone that going to space is a big deal for almost everyone, and it is a known fact to me that whenever I do something important for myself, pretty much everything goes out of my body as a liquid. This raises the following immediate question:

If an astronaut needs to go to the toilet during launch, what can they do and what do they need to do?

It would also be interesting to know what kind of preventative measures are taken (if any) before the launch.

Comment: A good dramatization of the problem can be seen in the movie *The Right Stuff*.  It's worth watching.

Comment: "what can/need to they do?"  Huh? Can you rephrase, please?

Comment: Well, it Depends.

Comment: Everything you need to know (or not) about peeing in space, with some nuggets of knowledge about before the launch: https://twitter.com/MaryRobinette/status/1152277166996017152

Comment: This is why you go before you leave on a long trip.

Comment: The christmas song "Let it snow" has the right tune for a short answer... "As long as you [have to go], Let it [fl]ow, let it [fl]ow, let it [fl]ow"  SCNR

Comment: @asdfex "Let it go, let it go, can't hold it back anymore." has new meaning...

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zu8hxR82I0w

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your approval of my edit suggestion, I was wondering what was wrong with it since they initially rejected it, I appreciate your approval a lot! Thanks again, cheers!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

They use three high-tech procedures:

- They schedule and ration their fluid and food intake.
- They go to the bathroom before the trip.
- They wear <strike>diapers</strike>, sorry, I meant [*Maximum Absorbency Garment*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_Absorbency_Garment).

In other words: they do exactly what you do before a trip. Minus the diaper, probably.

So, the answer to your question is the third point: they just pee in their pants, whereas points 1 and 2 are to avoid the problem in the first place.

Comment: Alan Shepard was the first astronaut to urinate into his suit. Without maximum absorbency garment. He had to suffer a long launch delay of two and a half hours for a mission less than 20 minutes.

Comment: Crewmembers told me they had to practice preflight to overcome a lifetime of habit / 'toilet training' and be able to go in the diaper.

Comment: American launches, at least, have a bathroom at the top of the tower, right before entering the rocket. Plus they quarantine for several days before launch to avert any risks.

Answer (score 29):

One of the main traditions and rituals of Soviet cosmonautics- all crew must urinate on the right rear wheel of their bus: https://www.bbc.com/future/article/20140610-the-strange-rituals-of-cosmonauts

[image]

With a [cleansing enema](https://www.airspacemag.com/daily-planet/please-dont-squeeze-the-astronaut-11638963/) launch day begins.

> To help ease our difficulty, we are offered a pre-launch enema. Administered by our flight surgeons, this allows us to launch with a clear mind and a clean colon.

Comment: it is funny, but unfortunately, that is not an answer.

Comment: @onurcanbektas that is true, but it is also a tradition to post this as an answer to *questions about to urination before flight*, I suppose this is also good luck?

Comment: Hmm... This ritual seems like it would have been problematic for the 3 female cosmonauts...

Comment: @reirab Pee funnel.

Comment: @reirab According to the linked article, "Female astronauts have been known to bring vials of their urine to splash on the wheel."

Comment: @uhoh oh, I didn't know that.

Comment: Everyone one wee's on vehicle wheels in Russia, it's to enhance non-slip effects in the cold weather. :) seriously they do.